# xamarin android multiple TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, tablelayout

I am develping a Android Xamarin App. I have to do a complex HTML, I decided to do it whith multiple tables (3)

When I display it, it looks like this.

[image]

Here is my script

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TableLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

      <Button
         android:text="1"
          android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />

      <Button
         android:text="2"
          android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
      <Button
         android:text="3"
          android:id="@+id/playBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

      <Button
         android:text="4"
          android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />

      <Button
         android:text="5"
          android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
      <Button
         android:text="6"
          android:id="@+id/playBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
    </TableRow>
    
  </TableLayout>

  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

      <Button
         android:text="7"
          android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />

      <Button
         android:text="8"
          android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
      <Button
        android:text="9"
          android:id="@+id/playBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

      <Button
         android:text="10"
          android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />

      <Button
         android:text="11"
          android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
      <Button
        android:text="12"
          android:id="@+id/playBtn"
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textSize="7sp" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I found is that 
Each table use 33%, but I need to put one after the other without empty spaces..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want a `LinearLayout` (or a derived class like `TableLayout`) to expand a child, just set its size to `wrap_content` and don't set a non null `layout_weight`.

So in you case :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button
                android:text="5"
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button
                android:text="9"
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button
                android:text="10"
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button
                android:text="11"
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button
                android:text="12"
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```